# Failing to @import bootstrap.css. Unable to open "bootstrap.css" resource not available

Tags: css, import, sass, bootstrap-4, extend

I'm new at web designing and I'm learning to use Flask. I've already done the structure of my web app and now I want to style it.

I've downloaded bootstrap Compiled CSS and JS, and I want to @import it into my customized scss file so then I can @extend some of it's features. My test code is:

```
@import 'C:/Users/lili_/Desktop/bootstrap-4.3.1-dist/css/bootstrap.css';
$navbar_color: red;
.my_navbar {
    @extend .navbar;
    background-color: $navbar_color;
}
```

The problem is that when I try to run sass and convert this into a css file, this error message shows up:

> "The selector ".navbar" was not found."

It shows the same error with any .class or #id that I've tried to @extend.
Also, when I open the "bootstrap.css" file by searching it in it's folder, it looks just fine, but when I try to follow the @import link (which I've copy-pasted on my test.scss) from the Visual Studio Code editor, an error window pops up claiming:

> "Unable to open 'bootstrap.css'
> resource not available"

Comment: You probably want to switch to a relative path instead of the absolute path you have provided. You probably have a folder for your project? Place your Bootstrap file in there (in an organised fashion `;)`) and import it into your Sass file with the relative path. Maybe [this reminder about paths](https://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/) will help!

Comment: Okey, I used a relative path and now at least I can follow the import link in Visual Studio Code, but I'm still not able to @extend anything: the same error massage than before.

Comment: I know it's a silly question, but you're sure there's a `.navbar` class in your bootstrap.css file?

Comment: jajaja, yes I'm positive. Also, it goes the same way for every other class i've tried to import

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing some things. For instance trying to `@import` a CSS file into a SCSS (SASS) file. At least, you have two reasonably options.

The first one would be to link the bootstrap CSS file into the \head tag into every HTML file (as is documented on the official [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/introduction/)). And, after that call link your CSS file rewriting some style properties.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

The other would be to integrate an [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-scss) that gives you Bootstrap partials in SCSS format that you can import into your main SCSS file.

Comment: Thanks! that actually seems to be the problem.